# How to fail test in gmock

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

Is there any macro in gmock that makes test to be failed?

Of course I can write something like this: `EXPECT_TRUE(false)` but maybe there is a better macro for that like `FAIL_TEST()` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ADD_FAILURE()` to force explicit failure of your unit test